# Just noticed a proposed "Education" .SE site

Tags: discussion, area51

As we get a number of off-topic questions about education (e.g, https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10414/books-on-gifted-education), I think support for an Education-related .SE is in many of our best interests here at Academia.SE:

> [Education.SE beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50826/education)

I thought I'd mention it here in case others wanted to follow/support it.

Comment: @Martin Didn't know that tag was available -- thanks!

Comment: I second yours.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I am a follower/supporter of that site.

I fully agree with your assessment that we ought to support the development of the Education.SE, for exactly the reasons that you have outlined.  Also, it could potentially mean referrals to here from people making academic related questions there.