# Please support development of new "Education" site

Tags: discussion, area51

We get so many questions that are about education but that are off topic.... Well, I noticed that Site 51 has a proposed "Education" site.  If this gets off the ground, we'll finally have someplace to send people with many of those off-topic questions!

To get started, the proposal needs "followers."

Check it out!

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/117355/education

Comment: "We get so many questions that are about education but that are off topic.... " I don't know about those. Could you give some examples?

Answer (score 5):

The [Education proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/117355/education) has been deleted due to inactivity at least twice (e.g., this was an [earlier Education proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50826/education)). The [Primary and Secondary Education proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110775/primary-and-secondary-education) has been closed due to inactivity and will eventually be deleted. The only educationally relevant proposal that I see is [Home Schooling](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/114491/homeschool) which is an obvious edge case.

There have been a number of these education type proposals in the past and we have discussed these. See for example:

[Just noticed a proposed "Education" .SE site](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/539/just-noticed-a-proposed-education-se-site)

and

[Should we create a site to help teachers with classroom technology?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1950/should-we-create-a-site-to-help-teachers-with-classroom-technology)

Comment: Thanks for the two links at the end of your post.  I had found the first; it's from five years ago.  I hadn't found the second (which is interesting but lacking in follow-up). // Suddenly, the Site51 proposal is gone.  Strange coincidence.

Comment: @aparente001 I don't know what you mean by lacking in follow-up. There was a [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90679/classroom-tech?referrer=p6Sj9uYUMG7oXm3CuwYaPg2), some of us followed it. It failed like all the others before it.

Comment: Please don't take my comment about lack of follow-up personally.  I saw that there was a proposal discussed at https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1950/should-we-create-a-site-to-help-teachers-with-classroom-technology.  It's clear that it died at some point, since it's no longer listed at Area51.  I don't know how close it got or how much support accumulated, since there were unfortunately no updates posted at https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1950/should-we-create-a-site-to-help-teachers-with-classroom-technology.